# Visual Studio Error and Output Window Contents

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I was recently asked by a co-worker if it was possible to automatically output the contents of these windows into a text file automatically each time the solution is built.

I have been using Visual Studio .NET since the original release.  I have not witness a way to do this, I also never had the need, so I simply could have glanced over it.

There must be a way to tell csc.exe and MSBuild to output to a file.

I forgot to mention this is a Visual Studio 2005 C# project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2010 (assuming it's the same for all others) each project generates a %name%.log text file in it's own directory by default. The solution does not though, so you may need to concatenate all these files or something similar.

Comment: Are you sure this is the case for C# projects? Afaik the log is only created for C++ projects.